# Do quantum mechanical effects such as uncertainty, tunnelling and entanglement play role in the electron transport system of respiration?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, cellular-respiration, energy, energy-metabolism

The electron transport system of aerobic respiration involves an extensive pathway of electron and proton transfer from one centre to another. Now, since they are quantum mechanical particles, shouldn't they exhibit quantum behaviours such as uncertainty, quantum superposition, quantum coherence, or maybe in some cases even tunnelling or entanglement? Do these behaviours have any definitive role to play in the entire process? And how exactly does the biological system deal with these quantum mechanical behaviours? What about the wave-like property of the electrons? Is there any "more *quantum-mechanical* model" of respiration?

Comment: Why electron transport rather than any other chemical reaction? They all involve movement of electrons. You could ask this question on SE Chemistry, where it would be more appropriate, but if you are looking for anything "suprachemical" to explain biological chemistry because it is biological, then you will be joining a long line of disappointed physicists starting with Max Delbrück.

Comment: I would suggest you look into the field of quantum biology. This TED talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLeEsYDlXJk) is a good place to start.

Comment: Check out work of [Judith Klinman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Klinman), in particular [Hydrogen Tunneling Links Protein Dynamics to Enzyme Catalysis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4066974/) (freely available Annual Review article)  and [Hydrogen tunneling in biology](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10381408/) and (an interesting wrt NAD(P)-linked enzymes) [Tunneling and dynamics in enzymatic hydride transfer](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16895320/). I wouldn't even think of doing just to the work of JK in an answer here: you will need to ask a specific question

Comment: Very good evidence for quantum-mechanical tunneling comes from the magnitude of the isotope effect in hydride and deuteride transfer reactions (The magnitude of the effect is often much greater than that predicted from  'classical' isotope effect theory, especially for primary isotope effects. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4066974/#T1), for example). The mass dependence of QM tunneling makes it more likely to occur in electron transfer reactions but _it can also occur_, in, say, an NADP-linked enzymic hydride transfer. All in the free Klinman article cited above –